# Moving to old project history to DVCS

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm coming late to the DVCS party after developing solo for a long time by doing my own version control with copies of folders.  For a small project, I would have essentially a folder structure that looked like this:

- project
- - development
- - release1.0
- - - release1.1 (for a bug fix)
- - - release1.2 (for a bug fix)
- - release 2.0 (for a new feature)

I'm now getting on board and learning DVCS using Mercurial (SourceTree) and BitBucket, and slowly learning the ropes with both the GUI and command line with some new projects where I could start fresh using DVCS.  I'd like to move some of my old projects into DVCS, but I don't want to lose my project history.  What is the best path to follow, or is it even worth the effort?

I'm thinking something along the lines of the following (attempting to use an HgFlow methodolgy):

1. Create repository using code from release 1.0
2. Commit files into the development branch
3. Add tag for release1.0
4. Merge into the master
5. From the development branch, create feature/hotfix branch for release 1.1
6. Copy files from release 1.1 into hotfix branch and commit
7. Merge hotfix branch into develop and master
8. Add tag for release 1.1
9. From the development branch, create feature/hotfix branch for release 1.2
10. Copy files from release 1.2 into hotfix branch and commit
11. Merge hotfix branch into develop and master
12. Add tag for release 1.2
13. etc.

Does this seem like a workable approach? What suggestions do you have?

Comment: Your approach looks good to me! (I've done a similar "copy/paste/commit process on older projects and it worked out fine.) You may want to use [tip #22](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks) when merging if the changes exist in both branches.

Comment: Edward, thanks. I will definitely need to do that with some of the issues where I incorporated changes manually from a bug fix in an earlier version into the development copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach is good. The only thing to add it to use [`hg addremove`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/addremove) before you commit the next version of your code. This command can find renamed files for you and will thus help you recreate an even more accurate history.

The workflow then becomes

1. Create repository
2. Copy files from `release1.0` into the working copy. They will all be seen as unknown (`? ...` lines in `hg status`).
3. Use `hg addremove` to schedule them all for addition. Adjust the `.hgignore` file to exclude build output before running `hg addremove`.
4. Commit and tag this as `1.0`.
5. Delete all files from your working copy using your normal OS delete command. The files will now be listed as missing (`! ...` lines in `hg status`).
6. Copy files from the `release1.1` into the working copy. Files that were changed compared to `release1.0` now show up as modified and (importantly) newly added files show up as unknown while removed files still show up as missing.
7. Run `hg addremove` to schedule the new files for addition and the missing files for removal. If a file `foo.c` in 1.0 was renamed to `bar.c` in 1.1, `foo.c` will show up as missing and `bar.c` will show up as unknown. When you run `hg addremove`, Mercurial will recognize this as a rename. Use the `--similarity` option to adjust how similar the files need to be for them to be considered a rename.
8. Commit and tag this as `1.1`.

Now repeat for the other releases. The important part is to clean the working copy between each code import — what way you make sure that each commit accurately reflects the state in the folders you used before.

Comment: Martin, thanks. I hadn't thought through what would happen with files that had been removed. This is a really helpful tip.

Comment: I'm still a newby, so it doesn't look like I CAN upvote: "Upvote requires 15 reputation points."  But I did accept your answer.

Comment: @kvibbertj: ah, sorry, I had forgotten about that restriction. Keep interacting with the site and you'll unlock all the features.